# Creating a .ini generator can't pass IP Address at all

Tags: python

What I'm looking to do is create a .ini generator I've got everything to work but this statement. There will be 5 agents but once I get one working the others are cake.

We have SUT 0 - 15, so do I need a range and why won't this print to the text document?

```
def ipDSS():
    ipDss = input('Please enter your SUT number:')
    if ipDSS <= 16:
        lines = ['agent_0_ip=192.168.5.14\n',
                 'agent_0_mac=99-11-99-11-99-11\n',
                 'agent_0_id=99\n']
        text_file.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a string to an integer. Try this instead:

```
if int(ipDSS) <= 16:
```

More info on comparisons in [manual](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons).